# Highcharts undefined in dynamic highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: Snap shot of code]

I am passing some json data from some functions to **function live(data)**  and its also being called after every two seconds by a function with data="".But I am getting this chart var declared on line 217 as undefined. help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Code instead of a picture will be appreciated:)

Comment: Please reproduce your example in the jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the chart inside `load` callback.

So change to:

`var length = this.series.length;`